# searching for vocabulary for machine translation

Tags: machine-translation

Searching for DE-EN vocabulary, that I can use in my machine translation.
It should consist of DE-EN phrases, words, sentences etc.

Got one from here http://www.manythings.org/anki/ , but searching for another one

Any thoughts please?

Comment: With "vocabulary" do you mean a list of all possible words in each language? If so, why don't you extract the vocabulary from freely available (for research purposes) large monolingual corpora like the WMT ones?

Comment: by vocabulary I mean german-english words, phrases and translations.Could you please give me a link on WMT?

Comment: You can find the latest WMT news translation datasets at http://www.statmt.org/wmt19/translation-task.html .

Comment: Then I understand that you need a bilingual lexicon at different levels (word, phrase, sentence), is that correct?

Comment: yes, correct, german-english (or vice versa) bilingual lexicon at different levels